# Windows 8 - Are transparency effects dead?

Tags: windows-8-preview, aero

I just read the [Windows 8 preview article](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5630/indepth-with-the-windows-8-consumer-preview/5) on Anandtech and noticed that they pointed out that in Windows 8 windows no longer have rounded corners and transparency/glass/"aero" effects.

One point not mentioned in the article was whether or not this is configurable, the result of having an underpowered graphics card, or likely to change in the final version of Windows 8.  So I was wondering if anyone can quickly tell me what the deal is with this?

Specifically, are all windows in Windows 8 slated to be 1) opaque and 2) square/non-rounded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Microsoft has decided to [remove Aero glass effects completely from Windows 8](http://www.theverge.com/2012/5/18/3029547/microsoft-windows-8-drops-aero-glass) (apart from the Taskbar), to make the interface for consistent with the new Start Screen and the Metro design language.

It is unknown at this time whether Aero Glass can be re-enabled via Windows 8 registry edits or other methods; feel free to edit this post if anyone discovers a method.